# Al momento de traer una imagen de la galería del dispositivo móvil me aparece el error: Unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode

Estoy utilizando el paquete image_picker para procesar la imagen y luego mostrarla cuando se haya elegido pero, en ciertas ocasiones funciona correctamente y en otras ocasiones la aplicación se bloquea y cuando miro la ventana de debug en la parte Pila de llamadas me aparece este error: FlutterError (Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.produmax/files/Pictures/scaled_product.jpg
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que utilizo para procesar la imagen

```dart
_seleccionarFoto () async {
  await _procesarImagen(ImageSource.gallery);
}

_tomarFoto () async {
  await _procesarImagen(ImageSource.camera);
}

_procesarImagen(ImageSource tipo) async {
  foto = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: tipo
  );

  if (foto != null) {
    _producto.imagePath = null;
  }

  setState(() { });
}
```

y este es el código para mostrar la imagen:

```dart
Widget _mostrarFoto() {
  if (_producto.imagePath != null) {
    final String url = utils.completeUrl(_producto.imagePath);
    return FadeInImage(
      image: NetworkImage(url),
      placeholder: AssetImage('assets/jar-loading.gif'),
      height: ScreenUtil.instance.setHeight(300.0),
      fit: BoxFit.contain
    );
  } else {
    return Image(
      image: AssetImage( foto?.path ?? 'assets/no-image.png'),
      height: ScreenUtil.instance.setHeight(300.0),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
  }
}
```

y es aquí donde utilizo las funciones _seleccionarFoto() y _tomarFoto()
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

`AssetImage` solo sirve para cargar imágenes que están dentro de tu proyecto de Flutter.
En el caso de `ImagePicker` estás obteniendo imágenes que se encuentran directamente en el dispositivo, por eso esa ruta completa.

Para solucionarlo, puedes usar el `FileImage`, ya que tienes acceso directamente al file.

```
Image(
      image: foto != null ? FileImage( foto) : AssetImage('assets/no-image.png'),
      height: ScreenUtil.instance.setHeight(300.0),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
```